# Poisson Percentile Bootstrap Intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, poisson-distribution

In Efron and Hastie's Computer Age Statistical Inference, they consider the problem of deriving confidence intervals for an estimated Poisson parameter. $\hat{\theta}=10$, where $\hat{\theta}\sim Pois(\theta)$. One possibility to constructing the confidence interval
is to use the standard interval: $\hat{C}_{std}=[\hat{\theta}\pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat{\theta}}]$. However, these are assumed symmetric around the parameter estimate, and this is clearly not the case if $\hat{\theta}\sim Pois(\theta)$.

However, if there exists a monotonic transformation, $m$, such that $m(\hat{\theta})\sim N(m(\theta),\sigma^2)$, then the standard intervals would work on that transformed scale. The variance stabilizing transform for the Poisson, yields $\sqrt{\hat{\theta}}\approx N(\sqrt{\theta},1/4)$, from which we backtransform to obtain $\hat{C}(10)= [4.76,17.17]$. This should have agreed with the percentile intervals.

Unfortunately, the book returns the percentile interval as $[4.18,16.73]$. I am confused as to how the percentile intervals should have been computed then, if not by exploiting the fact that if $m$ exists, then we may compute the standard intervals on the transformed scale. The full bootstrap procedure for $n$ observations is given in the book as follows: (I am not even sure it is applicable here because we only know that $\hat{\theta}\sim Pois(\theta)$)

1. Compute the bootstrap CDF, $\hat{G}(t)=\#\{\hat{\theta^*_b\leq t}\}/B$, where $B$ is the number of bootstrap samples, and $\theta^*_b$ are the bootstrap replicates. (Parametric or non-parametric)
2. Compute the empirical quantile function $\hat{G}^{-1}(\alpha)$ from the bootstrap replicates, and use the associated 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles to obtain a 95% confidence interval.

However, an exercise later in the chapter asks us to compute BCa corrected intervals, again using $\hat{\theta}\sim Pois(\theta)$ without simulation, which suggests to me that the percentile intervals should also be computed without simulation. Is there any other way to obtain the percentile interval without using simulation?